# Override base assignment function

Tags: r, methods

I'm attempting to override base (non-S3) methods to provide `colnames` methods for a custom R object. I want to do this with S3 not S4.

For the `colnames` accessor, this can be achieved by setting the base function to be the default method, then providing a method for my class:

```
colnames <-  function(x, ...) UseMethod("colnames")
colnames.default <- base::colnames
colnames.myclass <- function(x, ...) {
    # some code here
}
```

However, how would one override the setter method. I would hope *something* like this should work?

```
"colnames<-" <- function(x, value) UseMethod("colnames<-")
"colnames<-.default" <- "base::colnames<-"
"colnames<-.myclass" <- function(x, value) {
    print("Setting colnames for myclass")
    # Some code
}
```

However, this seems to fail to call the base function correctly for a regular matrix:

```
> test <- matrix(1:10, 5)
> colnames(test) <-  c("a", "b")
Error in UseMethod("colnames<-") : 
  no applicable method for 'colnames<-' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'integer', 'numeric')"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `colnames<-.default` to a character string (i.e. not a function). That's not going to work.

```
"colnames<-.default" <- "base::colnames<-"
```

Use backticks to reference objects with non-syntactic names.

```
`colnames<-.default` <- base::`colnames<-`
```